# Count different groups in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, count

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
#   |   A   |   B   |   MoreFieldsHere
1       1       1
2       1       3
3       1       5
4       2       6
5       2       7
6       3       9
```

B is associated to A in an 1:n relationship. The table could've been created with a join for example.

I want to get both the total count and the count of different A.
I know I can use a query like this:

```
SELECT v1.cnt AS total, v2.cnt AS num_of_A
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM SomeComplicatedQuery
    WHERE 1=1
          -- AND SomeComplicatedCondition
) v1,
(
    SELECT COUNT(A) AS cnt
    FROM SomeComplicatedQuery
    WHERE 1=1
      -- AND SomeComplicatedCondition
    GROUP BY A
) v2
```

However `SomeComplicatedQuery` would be a complicated and slow query and `SomeComplicatedCondition` would be the same in both cases. And I want to avoid calling it unnessesarily. Aside from that if the query changes, you need to make sure to change it in the other place too, making it prone to error and creating (probably unnessesary) work.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: *"Is there a way to do this more efficiently?"* make the `WHERE` more efficient? First thing would be remove the `1=1` as that's just a waste of the compiler's time. next would be the share said `WHERE` so we can help make it perform better. Also, if *"`SomeComplicatedCondition`"* is the same why not have `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(A`) in the same statement?

Comment: Well, there where is built dynamically by .net code. there may be different numbers of conditions, including 0, which is why all conditions are added with `AND` in front of them. the 1=1 thing makes it easier to handle. Also Count(A) does count every line where A is not `NULL`, not the distinct A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, COUNT(DISTINCT A) AS num_of_A
FROM (. . . ) q
```